# Pulling Inner Text of Nodes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a very simple XML file that looks something like:

```
<Reshelving>
<Location>LOC1</Location>
<Location>LOC2</Location>
</Reshelving>
```

I have a vb.net form that I want to display the location text in a list box in using the following code:

```
 Public Function loadFile(ByRef filename As String) As Boolean
    Try
        reshelvingDocument.Load(filename)
        Dim myNodes As XmlNodeList
        Dim name As XmlNode
        myNodes = reshelvingDocument.SelectNodes("Reshelving")
        lstHomeLocations.Items.Clear()
        For Each location As XmlNode In myNodes
            name = location.SelectSingleNode("Location")
            If name Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            End If
            lstHomeLocations.Items.Add(name.InnerText)
        Next
        If lstHomeLocations.Items.Count = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        lstHomeLocations.SelectedIndex = 0
        reshelvingFile = filename
        Me.Text = "Reshelving Settings - " & reshelvingFile
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim message As String = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Sub LstHomeLocationsSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim HomeLocation As XmlNode, HomeLocationData As XMLNode
    HomeLocation = reshelvingDocument.SelectSingleNode("Reshelving[Location=""" & lstHomeLocations.SelectedItem & """]")
End Sub
```

The form will only show the first Node (LOC1) but not display any additional ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need one more loop.  myNodes would contain one node from the example, but would have 2 child nodes, each with inner text.  Maybe something more like:

```
For Each location As XmlNode In myNodes
 For Each n As XmlNode In location.SelectNodes("Location")
     lstHomeLocations.Items.Add(n.InnerText)
 Next
Next
```